# Select tag Stuck on one option

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with one of my select tags. I am trying to make a input type text read only and a text area readonly alternating between the two depending on the a value of a select. But my select tag is stuck and cant change it when i click on it. Also when i refresh my page the select tag is on option "Onderwerp" instead of "Titel" but my first option is "Titel".

My Javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function read()
   {
       current=document.getElementById("soortvraag");
       if(current.value="onderwerp")
       {
          document.getElementById('auteur').readOnly = true;
          document.getElementById('antwoord').readOnly = false;
       } else {
          document.getElementById('auteur').readOnly = false;
          document.getElementById('antwoord').readOnly = true;
       }
   }
</script>
```

My Html:

```
<p><label for="soortvraag">Soortvraag:</label> 
<p><select id="soortvraag" onchange="read()" name="soortvraag">
     <option value="titel">Titel</option>
     <option value="onderwerp">Onderwerp</option>
</select></p>  
<p><label for="vraag">Titel:</label>
   <label style="padding-left:95px;"for="auteur">Auteur:</label>
</p>
<p><input type="text" name="vraag" pattern=".{4,20}" required title="4 tot 20 Tekens" value=""> 
   <input type="text" id="auteur" name="auteur" value=""></p>
<p><label for="antwoord">Antwoord:</label></p>
<p><textarea id="antwoord" name="antwoord" style="width:400px;height:100px;"></textarea></p>
```

And on my body i have:

```
<body onLoad="read()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correctly comparing the value of your `select` element.

This assignment (**`=`**):

```
if(current.value = "onderwerp")
```

Should be a comparision (**`==`**):

```
if(current.value == "onderwerp")
```

This causes all the issues you're describing.

Comment: It works like charm now! thank you very much :) won't be making that mistake again ;)